# Using the Fourier transform in order to derive a limit

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

SNf is finite the Fourier sum of this function:

SNf is:

[image]

[image]

I can't see how to calculate this limit:

[image]

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I figured out the Fourier series of the function, I thought maybe the solution was related to Dirichlet kernel but I couldn't move forward with the thought.

Comment: Am I in the right direction? what can I use in order to solve this?